# How do I play WMA files?

Tags: codecs, wma

Since I made the upgrade to 12.04 I can't play WMA files. I added Medibuntu, install w64codecs, `non-free-codecs` but they don't work. I have also installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you ran "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras"?

Comment: Yes I have also installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution: remove the folder `.gstreamer` in the home directory.

Comment: This doesn't work any more. Is there still a way to play WMA files in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Thucydides411
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`

Comment: I've tried that as well, but still can't play wma files. I get a segmentation fault every time I try to play them in Totem or VLC.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try using VLC player which worked in mine without the need of downloading codecs separately, I found the following [link](http://www.ubun2.com/question/205/how_play_wmv_wma_format_video_files_linux) which was similar to your problem, Hope it helps

Comment: Thank for your help but I don't want use only VLC. I will make a clean install of 12.04.

Comment: smplayer or mpv, both work here.  Or ffmpeg with mp3 as an output format.  I don't know if there's DRM junk in what I just tried or not.